Playwright in a Docker suddenly stopped working "Executable doesn't exist at /home/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1124/chrome-linux/chrome"
It was working fine up until yesterday.
Full setup is Playwright in Express in a Docker container in Google Cloud Run. Preferably headful but I'd accept anything at this stage.
browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1124/chrome-linux/chrome
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

My original Dockerfile:
# Start from a base Node.js image
FROM node:latest

# Install necessary packages: XVFB and fonts
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        xvfb \
        x11-xkb-utils \
        xfonts-100dpi \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        xfonts-scalable \
        x11-apps \
        clang \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libcups2 \
        libatspi2.0-0 \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libgbm1 \
        libxkbcommon0 \
        libasound2 \
    && apt-get clean

# Set display environment variable for XVFB
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Create a working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install Playwright browsers
RUN npx playwright install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port your app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Run XVFB, then start your Express application
CMD xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" node index.js

package.json: "playwright": "^1.44.1"
index.js:
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });


I've tried:

Zenika's image using the Dockerfile provided

FROM zenika/alpine-chrome:with-node

ENV PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD 1
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=chrome package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]


Playwright browsers

using Node:14.10

executablePath = 'usr/bin/chromium-browser'


and a lot of other minor variations.

Ok so after 3 days of trying out all the online solutions and after trying out puppeteer, I decided to solve this on own.

I downloaded the linux x64 chromium in Google's Chromium browser snapshots (chrome-linux.zip)

I added the unzipped folder to the codebase.

I updated the browser initialization to this:
 const browser = await chromium.launch({
     executablePath: './chrome-linux/chrome',
     headless: false
 });



